# Reading data from Raspberry pi using TCP/IP block

Tags: python, matlab, csv, simulink

I am trying to send data to the raspberry pi using TCP/IP Send block from Simulink. Can anyone suggest how I can read data from raspberry pi and write it to the CSV format ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try scripting a program to listen for the TCP message, and dump it to a CSV file in the same program.

For example, using `python` (copy-pasted with some modifications from https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) with `socket` library, you can write a program running in raspi that listens for the csv messages:

```
import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

data_rcv = ''
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    data_rcv += data
conn.close()

with open('/path/to/csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  csvfile.write(data_rcv)
```

I believe `python` comes with Raspbian by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The scripts work for TCP_IP 127.0.0.1. But when I put the ip address of my remote machine, it says "socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address". I guess we need to do port forwarding for each ip address that i am trying to access. If yes, how ?? Thank you again though.

Comment: i guess you are trying to hit from Simulink (i assume this is the remote machine?) -> Raspberry Pi.
In that case, your "TCP_IP" should be set to the Raspberry Pi's IP and not the remote machine. Also, I'm assuming that pinging the raspberry pi's IP from Simulink works (i.e. no network related barriers e.g. firewall, diff subnets, etc).

Comment: Hi chaooder!! I am using the IP address of my raspberry pi for "TCP_IP" and also I can ping from my remote machine running MATLAB Simulink to the RPi's IP address. I even tried port forwarding from the router. Still, the error persists. It shows the error on "File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py, line 228, in meth      return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)       socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use "

Comment: Do you have another service running on the same port of raspi? Looks like a clash in IP+Port with another service (use "netstat -pln" to check)

Comment: Yes, I had another service running on the same port of raspi. The problem is solved!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Chaooder!! I can read and write data to the raspberry pi. But, the data I receive is random Chinese like characters. Is there any encoding format that we need to add to the code??

Comment: you can perhaps try to add a utf-16 or 32 encoding in the open() function in the second last line:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o 
also, if the earlier answer helps your original question, perhaps accept the answer? :)